# Hardhat impersonateAccount returns an empty "whale" wallet

Tags: hardhat, mocha, flash-loans

I am impersonating a whale wallet so that I transfer ETH from that wallet to my flashloan contract for the sake of performing an example flash loan using my test script. I check the address to make sure it has sufficient funds, and the console log tells me it does. However, the balance I have in the impersonated account is 0.

What is my problem here? I double checked my syntax, checked documentation, checked my hardhat config, which is set to be a fork of mainnet, and asked chatGPT, and everything seems to match what I see in examples so I am unsure what the issue here could be. Any help is much appreciated!!

**My FlashTest.js file (see below for output of npx hardhat test):**

```
const { loadFixture } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers, network } = require("hardhat");

// Note: Replace the path with the correct path to your ABI file
const abiFlashLoan = require("../artifacts/contracts/ProjectTide.sol/Arbitrage.json").abi;
const { getAddress } = require("ethers/lib/utils");
const USDC = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2";//"0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48"; using WETH now to also cover gas fees
const PEPE = "0x6982508145454Ce325dDbE47a25d4ec3d2311933";
const WHALE = "0xF04a5cC80B1E94C69B48f5ee68a08CD2F09A7c3E";
const borrowedToken = USDC;
const uniRouterAddress = '0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d';
const sushiRouterAddress = '0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F';

describe("FlashLoan", function() {
   async function create_whale() {
       const provider = ethers.provider;
       const whaleBalance = await provider.getBalance(WHALE);
       expect(WHALE).not.equal("0");
       //impersonate whale account
       await network.provider.request({
           method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
           params: [WHALE],
       });
       const whaleWallet = await provider.getSigner(WHALE);
       await console.log("whaleWallet.getBalance: ",await whaleWallet.getBalance());
       expect(await whaleWallet.getBalance()).not.equal("0");

       //ensure usdc balance
       const abi = [
           "function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)",
           "function balanceOf(address _owner) view returns (uint256 balance)"
       ];
       const contractUSDC = new ethers.Contract(borrowedToken, abi, provider);
       const balanceUSDC = await contractUSDC.balanceOf(WHALE);  
       console.log("Balance of USDC Whale : ", balanceUSDC);
       expect(balanceUSDC).not.equal("0");
       
       return {whaleWallet};
   }
   describe("Deployment and Testing", function () {
       it("Deploys and performs Flash Loan arbitrage", async function () {
           await console.log("here is the beginning");
           await console.log("Connected to network:", network.name);
           let {whaleWallet} = await loadFixture(create_whale);
           const provider = ethers.provider;
           //Deploys
           const FlashLoan = await ethers.getContractFactory("Arbitrage");
           let flashLoan = await FlashLoan.deploy();
           await flashLoan.deployed();
           await console.log("FlashLoan contract deployed: \t", flashLoan.address);

           //send money for fake arb calculation
           let usdcAmt = ethers.utils.parseUnits("6", 18);
           const abi = [
               "function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)",
               "function balanceOf(address _owner) view returns (uint256 balance)"
           ];
           const contractUsdc= new ethers.Contract(borrowedToken, abi, whaleWallet);
           await console.log("BEFORE");
           console.log("Balance of Whale Wallet:", ethers.utils.formatEther(await provider.getBalance(WHALE)));
           //await console.log(await contractUsdc.balanceOf(whaleWallet.address));
           const txUsdc = await contractUsdc.transfer(flashLoan.address, usdcAmt);
           await console.log("AFTER");
           const receiptTxUsdc = await txUsdc.wait();

           const contractBalUsdc = contractUsdc.balanceOf(flashLoan.address);
           await console.log("wallet usdc: ", contractBalUsdc);

           //Initialize Flash Loan Params
           const amountBorrow = ethers.utils.parseUnits("30",18);
           const loanTokens = [0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48]; // Your tokens array
           const amounts = [1]; // Your amounts array
           const userData = ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
             ['address', 'address', 'address'],
             [PEPE, sushiRouterAddress, uniRouterAddress]
           );

           const contractFlashLoan = new ethers.Contract(flashLoan.address, abiFlashLoan, whaleWallet);
           
           await console.log("before flash");
           const txFlashloan = await contractFlashLoan.makeFlashLoan([USDC],[amountBorrow], userData);
           await console.log("after flash");
       }
)});  
})
```

**console output of npx hardhat test:**

```
Arbitrage
    Deployment and Testing
here is the beginning
Connected to network: hardhat
whaleWallet.getBalance:  BigNumber { value: "0" }
Balance of USDC Whale :  BigNumber { value: "564994956307519990645221" }
FlashLoan contract deployed:     0x31403b1e52051883f2Ce1B1b4C89f36034e1221D
BEFORE
Balance of Whale Wallet: 0.0
      1) Deploys and performs Flash Loan arbitrage


  0 passing (3s)
  1 failing

  1) Arbitrage
       Deployment and Testing
         Deploys and performs Flash Loan arbitrage:
     InvalidInputError: sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The max upfront cost is: 5290247638023396 and the sender's account only has: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need one more step: set_balance for Whale address

Refer: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/reference#hardhat_setbalance